# AngularJS validation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I have some form fields where I only want to allow letters for them to be ('ng-valid'). I have it like the following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Example.field1" ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z]/" />
```

It works correctly if you only type in letters, or only type in non-letters, but if they are mixed it won't mark the field as invalid. Can someone tell me why this would be happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern

```
/^([A-Za-z]+)$/
```

Right now you are saying that you want one character anywhere in the string.

Comment: You are a hero. Thank you.